# Does Google Script have an equivalent to python's Session object?

Tags: session, google-apps-script, http-headers

I have this python script and I want to get Google Script equivalent but I do not know how to "pass" whatever needs to be passed between next get or post request once I log in.

```
import requests
import json

# login
session = requests.session()
data = {
    'LoginName': 'name',
    'Password': 'password'
}
session.post('https://www.web.com/en-CA/Login/Login', data=data)
session.get('https://www.web.com//en-CA/Redirect/?page=Dashboard')


# get customer table
data = {
    'page': '1',
    'pageSize': '100'
}
response = session.post('https://www.web.com/en-CA/Reporting', data=data)
print(response.json())
```

I wonder if there is an equivalent to `.session()` object from python's requests module. I did search google but could not find any working example. I am not a coder so I dot exactly know that that .session() object does. Would it be enough to pass headers from response when making new request?

**UPDATE**
I read in some other question that Google might be using for every single `UrlFetchApp.fetch` different IP so login and cookies might not work, I guess.

Comment: I think that when you want to achieve `session()` in python using Google Apps Script, it is required to retrieve and add cookie for header in UrlFetchApp. Because in the current stage, UrlFetchApp has no method for directly keeping cookie and using it to the next request. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) But unfortunately, I cannot understand about the specification of the server you want to use. So in the current stage, I cannot propose the complete modified script for your script yet. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: You dont have poor skills. The thing is that I do not exactly know what the python session() module does so I do not know what exactly I need to do in Google Apps Script. Or if it is even possible. That is why I asked this question.

Comment: Thank you for replying. If my understanding is correct, when `session()` is used, the multiple request can be achieved by keeping the cookie. So in order to achieve this with Google Apps Script, for example, I thought that the cookie is retrieved at 1st request and the cookie is included in the request header for 2nd request. In this case, your goal might be achieved. When I could understand about your server, I thought that I might be able to propose the modified script.

Comment: that is what I thought too. I do not understand how cookies work, where they are stored. It looks like this is the way. Store cookies in header and send it in next request.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a sample script as an answer. The sample script can achieve that the cookie can be retrieved from 1st request and the retrieved cookie can be used for next request. But, unfortunately, I have no information of your actual server and I cannot test for your actual URLs. So I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution of your issue. I apologize for about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to achieve your python script with Google Apps Script.

#### Issue and workaround:

If my understanding is correct, when `session()` of python is used, the multiple requests can be achieved by keeping the cookie. In order to achieve this situation using Google Apps Script, for example, I thought that the cookie is retrieved at 1st request and the retrieved cookie is included in the request header for 2nd request. Because, in the current stage, `UrlFetchApp` has no method for directly keeping cookie and using it to the next request.

From above situation, when your script is converted to Google Apps Script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  const url1 = "https://www.web.com/en-CA/Login/Login";
  const url2 = "https://www.web.com//en-CA/Redirect/?page=Dashboard";
  const url3 = "https://www.web.com/en-CA/Reporting";
  
  // 1st request
  const params1 = {
    method: "post",
    payload: {LoginName: "name", Password: "password"},
    followRedirects: false
  }
  const res1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url1, params1);
  const headers1 = res1.getAllHeaders();
  if (!headers1["Set-Cookie"]) throw new Error("No cookie");

  // 2nd request
  const params2 = {
    headers: {Cookie: JSON.stringify(headers1["Set-Cookie"])},
    followRedirects: false
  };
  const res2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2, params2);
  const headers2 = res2.getAllHeaders();

  // 3rd request
  const params3 = {
    method: "post",
    payload: {page: "1", pageSize: "100"},
    headers: {Cookie: JSON.stringify(headers2["Set-Cookie"] ? headers2["Set-Cookie"] : headers1["Set-Cookie"])},
    followRedirects: false
  }
  const res3 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url3, params3);
  console.log(res3.getContentText())
}
```

- By this sample script, the cookie can be retrieved from 1st request and the retrieved cookie can be used for next request.
- Unfortunately, I have no information of your actual server and I cannot test for your actual URLs. So I'm not sure whether this sample script directly works for your server.
- And, I'm not sure whether `followRedirects: false` in each request is required to be included. So when an error occurs, please remove it and test it again.
- About the method for including the cookie to the request header, `JSON.stringify` might not be required to be used. But, I'm not sure about this for your server.

#### Reference:

- [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

Comment: It looks like the first request works well. I get the same result like from python but the second request returns `<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/site/ ....` it is ok to get HTML but something with data, content. This one basically an error.

Comment: @Radek Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your error message, it is considered that the reason of this is due to `followRedirects: false`. So when this line is removed, what result will you obtain? But I have no information of your actual server and I cannot test for your actual URLs. So I'm not sure whether that modified sample script directly works for your server. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: you are right. Removing the `followRedirects: false` looks like solved the issue. I have to investigate more. Thank you.

Comment: @Radek Thank you for replying and testing it again. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this:

```
var nl = getNewLine()

function getNewLine() {
    var agent = navigator.userAgent

    if (agent.indexOf("Win") >= 0)
        return "\r\n"
    else
        if (agent.indexOf("Mac") >= 0)
            return "\r"

    return "\r"

}

pagecode = 'import requests
import json

# login
session = requests.session()
data = {
    \'LoginName\': \'name\',
    \'Password\': \'password\'
}
session.post(\'https://www.web.com/en-CA/Login/Login\', data=data)
session.get(\'https://www.web.com//en-CA/Redirect/?page=Dashboard\')


# get customer table
data = {
    \'page\': \'1\',
    \'pageSize\': \'100\'
}
response = session.post(\'https://www.web.com/en-CA/Reporting\', data=data)
print(response.json())'

document.write(pagecode);
```

I used [this program](https://stevs.net/converter/)